# MongoDB node.js : Delete a document automatically after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ttl

I want to delete a document automatically after 10 seconds of creating It , for doing this I use mongodb TTL ,But the timer doesn't works properly and deletes the document after 40 seconds or 50 seconds or 20, So where is my mistake ?

```
  await db.collection("admin_msg").insertOne({ createdAt: new Date() });
  await db.collection("admin_msg").createIndex({ createdAt: 1}, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expireAfterSeconds` doesn't guarantee immediate deletion of the document. The deletions are done by a background job which runs every minute. This job is low-priority and can be postponed by MongoDB when the current load is high. So when it's important for your use-case that the expire times are respected accurately to the second, then you should add the expiration time to the find-query to make sure you don't get any documents which are already supposed to be deleted.

This feature is documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

I would **not** recommend to create an own job to automatically delete documents and runs at shorter intervals, as that might not only cause quite a lot of load, it might also not actually fix the problem, because those deletions might also get delayed when the oplog gets too long. Checking the expiration on retrieval is a far more reliable option.

Answer (score 1):

As the [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#timing-of-the-delete-operation) states:

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60
> seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the
> period between the expiration of the document and the running of the
> background task.

So if the document needs to be deleted exactly after 10 seconds you're going to have to write your own service, job or other programmable method to delete a document after a specific amount of time.